# Unique argument of column annotation is not considered

Tags: spring

In the entity attribute I make it to be unique :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String role_code;

    ...

}
```

But at runtime when inserting a new record then no exception is raised , nor console ! Although database is correctly set as the role_code column is a varchar2 primary key :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("role_details") Role role) {

    roleDao.saveOrUpdate(role);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/adminrole/");

}
```

So how to enforce unique constraint at the entity level ?

Comment: Post your code testing that no exception is thrown.

Comment: I updated my post to include the code executing the insert.

Comment: You're calling saveOrUpdate(). Your entity has an ID already, so saveOrUpdate() does an update.

Comment: you're right @JB !

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", indexes = {@Index(name = "some_index_name", columnList = "role_code", unique = true})
public class Role { ... }
```